# Jquery binding loop variable to getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for loop that GETs a json array and populates it in a table along with another list's variables. My problem is I am not able to access i inside the get method. But I have mylist and all its contents inside. I tried binding the function to a variable i using bind(this,i) but that says .getJSON() is not a function. Here's the relevant code.

```
var mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
for (i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {

    urlstr = "/" + mylist[i]; // Generate url
    $.getJSON(urlstr, function(data) {
        html = "<tr><td>" + mylist[i] + "</td><td>" + data.string[0] + "</td></tr>";
        $("#tableresult").append(html); //this returns undefined for mylist[i]
        console.log(i); //this returns 3 which is the length of list
    });

}
```

In short I need the variables outside getJSON be accessible within getJSON.
Can someone please help? Thanks and regards.

Comment: You seem to have some string boundary issues.

Comment: urlstr="/"+mylist[i]; . . try this

Comment: The issue with `i` being `3` is that you loop over the items, calling getJSON, but before the first callback gets called, the loop is done already, resulting in `i` being 3 for each callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be no different from binding the loop variable in practically any other loop. Since you are working with an array, the cleanest approach is to use `Array#forEach`:

```
var mylist = ["a", "b", "c"];
mylist.forEach(function (item) {
    var urlstr = "/" + item;
    $.getJSON(urlstr, function(data){
         var html = "<tr><td>" + item + "</td><td>" + 
                    data.string[0] + "</td></tr>";
         $("#tableresult").append(html);
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works well but supposing I have a few more variables outside getJSON and this function, how would I acces them inside?

Comment: Eg, i have another variable myvar=5 beside mylist. How would I access it inside?

Comment: @Tania You can just use it like you normally would. Shouldn't be a problem as long as its value isn't undergoing changes while the requests are taking place.

Comment: It says myvar is undefined @JLRishe

Comment: @Tania Could you show me the code where you're trying to use it?

Comment: Its value is modified within another function btw.

Comment: @Tania Is that supposed to be an answer to my request?

Comment: No.. Sorry,  I missed that. `var myvar;function somefn(){myvar="abcde"}var mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
for (i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {console.log(myvar);}`

Comment: @Tania Ok, so that should work as long as `somefn()` is called before the code that does the JSON requests. `myvar` won't have a value until `somefn()` is called.

Comment: Okay. if I get myvar inside another getJSON will that work? `var myvar;$.get(url,function(){myvar='abcde'});var mylist = ["a", "b", "c"] for (i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {console.log(myvar);}`

Answer (score 1):

please ensure your php return data is json.

for example:

```
$data['something'] = 'data';
echo json_encode($data);
```

and using function for get index (i):

```
 $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(field + " ");
        });
    });
```

Comment: okay, have you try : $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(field + " ");
        });